# How to fix a code while transferring a file made in python 2 to python 3

Tags: python

How can I fix the code:

```
Subtotal = input("What is your Subtotal? ")
input_tax = input('What is the Tax? Please enter as a decimal ')
input_tip  = input('What is the Tip? Please enter as a decimal ')
Tax = float(input_tax) * float(Subtotal)
Tip = float(input_tip) * float(Subtotal)
Total = float(Tip) + float(Tax) + float(Subtotal)
print ("Your Total is $") + str(Total)
```

when the error message is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\Tip_and_Tax_Calculator.py", line 7, in <module>
    print ("Your Total is $") + str(Total)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'str'`
```

Comment: `print ("Your Total is $" + str(Total))`.

Comment: This is because `print` returns `None` in Python 3.

Comment: You can do `print(f'Your Total is ${Total}')` with python >= 3.6

Answer (score 2):

You just need to move the `str(Total)` inside the parenthesis. In Python 3 [`print`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) is a function. So right now Python is trying to add the return value of `print` (which is always `None`) to `str(Total)` (which is a string).

So, change the last line to:

```py
print("Your Total is $" + str(Total))
```

---

Also, from Python 3 you have more elegant ways to format strings:

- For Python >=3.0: the string [`format`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) method:

  ```
  print("Your Total is ${}".format(Total))
  ```
- For Python >=3.6: [f-strings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/):

  ```
  print(f"Your Total is ${Total}")
  ```